# Spark 2.1.0 на кластере со Spark 1.6.2

Tags: apache-spark

На hadoop кластере используется spark 1.6.2 (CDH-5.8.3).
Я хочу запустить поток с использованием spark 2.1.0.
Подложил jar libpath (spark-core_2.10-2.1.0.jar, spark-hive_2.10-2.1.0.jar, spark-network-common_2.10-2.1.0.jar, spark-sql_2.10-2.1.0.jar).
Поток валится с ошибкой:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.isInInterpreter()Z
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.initializeLogging(Logging.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.initializeIfNecessary(Logging.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.log(ApplicationMaster.scala:635)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:649)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
```

В jar spark-core не нашёл класс Logging.class, из которого вызывается метод isInInterpreter(), поэтому делаю вывод, что jar файл spark-core берётся не тот, который я подложил. Есть у кого-нибудь догадки как решить проблему.

Comment: вы можете просто установить spark 2.1.0 параллельно 1.6.2(то есть надо именно загрузить и распаковать spark-2.1.0 binary). Не забудьте обновить`SPARK_HOME`. Так же можно просто использовать `spark-submit` из необходимой версии

Answer (score 0):

Apache Spark при запуске *на Hadoop-кластере* по сути использует от Hadoop'а только его менеджер ресурсов - YARN. Таким образом, на одном и том же кластере можно запустить разные версии Spark'а. Для этого необходимо следующее:

- скачать подходящую версию Apache Spark [отсюда](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) (в CDH-5.8.3 используется Hadoop 2.6, поэтому скачать нужно версию `Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.6`)
- распаковать полученный архив в любую папку (обновлять `SPARK_HOME` при этом не обязательно)
- установить переменную среды `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` или `YARN_CONF_DIR`, где указать путь до папки, в которой располагаются файлы конфигурации Hadoop (в принципе в CDP уже должно быть установлено)
- перейти в подпапку `bin` той папки, куда распакован новый Spark, и запустить задачу с использованием `spark-submit` с указанием `--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster`